# HttpURLConnection to Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to connect from a java desktop application to a jsp Servlet to send a file.

Clientcoding:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
URL url = null;
url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/emobile/AddTripMobile");
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
urlConnection.getOutputStream());

out.write(12); //The data to send
out.flush();
```

If I connect with the desktop application to the server nothing happens.
(I set a breakpoint in the doGet and doPost)

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are using netbeans then change the port no to 8084.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following :

```
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
out.write(12); //The data to send
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the output stream.